# Android architecture - Where should a model live across activities?

Tags: android, mobile

I'm just starting android development, and am not certain what the best practice is around creating a new app for data/model information. In MVVM or MVC architectures, I would normally have a have a shared object for core data model. For example, if I have the concept of a customer, and there is data that needs to exist on all pages (ex: customer name), that would a global customer object.

What is the right way to store this information in Android? I'm essentially looking to make a call to a web service, obtain core information, and then have it available to all activities. I'm planning on creating a new background service to obtain the data, but am not sure where to store it afterwards.

Is the best practice to create a model and pass it between all activities as needed? That seems like I'd be binding the activities pretty tightly to each other, though maybe that's not a concern.  Saving to the local db for each activity is the other approach I've considered, but reading it out from the db on every subsequent activity seems like unnecessary overhead.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the right way, but I've tried the approach of the DB and also found it to be too much overhead. I've also tried plain text files, but then parsing them was a bit of a pain. I've settled now on JSON files. Works well for me. Easy to store and easy to parse using the `org.json.*` libraries. I store the JSON files themselves on external media using `context.getExternalFilesDir` to find the media on the user's device. There are, of course, many other approaches, but this one works for me -- minimal code and robust.

Comment: This, together with the static class below that Leo has suggested seems like it would work quite well for me.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want a local SQLite database. If, you are concerned that you are reading the db too often, I would suggest two things.

1) Each time, only read what you need from the db – you don't have to read all of the data.

2) You could create a class to hold a singleton object that you read from your db. Something like:

```
    public class CustomerList{
    private static List<Customer> sList;

    public List<Customer> readList(Context context){
        if (sList == null){
            sList = readFromDB(context);
        }
        return sList;
    }
}
```